# Does this sound like a native speaker?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, translation

does this sentence sound like a native speaker?

明日から、問題が有れば、私に話す前に、まずメールで会話の内容を送信します。お願いします。

Any suggestion are welcome. Thank you so much.

Comment: Are you also including the usage of kanji in your definition of "sound like a native speaker?" If so, it's quite bizarre to write 有れば but then write はなす and おねがい.

Comment: Aww, sorry, I mean including kanji too. I'll update the question.

Comment: Did you mean "If there is any problem, please send me an email about the conversation, before you talk to me in person."? If so, you should write 送信してください。 not 送信します。

Comment: Any chance you could tell us what you're trying to say? It's not perfectly clear what exactly you're attempting to convey, so kind of hard to rephrase

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's basically proofreading which to me is a glorified translation request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 明日から、問題が有れば、私に話す前に、まずメールで会話の内容を送信します。お願いします。

Generally okay, but a few things that do look and sound unnatural.

For starters, not many people write 有る with kanji. It's not wrong, but considering its rarity most Japanese people would pick up on that, and a few will even ask you why you're using 有れば rather than あれば.

Also, your usage of commas is a bit heavy for any language, even English, and makes your speech flow much less.

Other than that, 〜してください is a natural ending for the first sentence rather than します. This also makes the latter お願いします redundant.

> 明日から問題があれば、私に話す前に(まず)メールで会話の内容を送信してください。

There are still some issues with pronoun drops and questions about who does what, as Choko points out in her comments. You need to point out who's receiving the mail that's being sent. This is where it's hard to see what you mean without a better translation, or the meaning you want to convey.

Choko brings up suggestions. Based upon my guess on what you're trying to translate from English, I take it you're trying to translate "From tomorrow, if you have any problems, email me about what you want to discuss before talking to me in person." This gives us roughly:

> 明日から問題があれば、私に直接話に来る前に、まずメールで用件を教えてください。(depending on what you're trying to say)

The sentence I had in mind from the start after reading your sentence was along the lines of

> 明日から問題があれば、私に直接話しかける前にメールで用件を教えてください。
>
> From tomorrow, if you have any problems, before talking to me in person, send me an email telling me [what you want to talk about].

Tell me if my attempt at a translation back is along the lines of what you wanted to say -- I can't tell based off only your initial sentence, but I think I got the right impression.

Also, for more info about 用件, the word Choko (and I afterwards) used, see http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E7%94%A8%E4%BB%B6. It's hard to translate, so better you get an idea yourself. A good initial thought would be to consider it "a matter."

Comment: 「明日からは、問題があれば私に話す前にまずメールで会話の内容を送信します。」と書き直したとしても、意味がわかりません。「送信します」とだけ言うと「私が送信します」という意味になるからです。「私に話す前に、私が送信する」？？変でしょう。

Comment: 「明日からは、問題があれば私に話す前にまずメールで会話の内容を送信してください。」と書き直しても、「送信してください」と言いつつ「話す前」というのが変です。「話‌​す」はメールで伝えることも含むからです。「口頭で話しかける前に、メールしろ」という意味なら、「私に直接話しに来る前に、まずメールで・・・」とか「まずメールで～～を‌​送信してから、私に話しに来てください。」などがいいのではないかと。

Comment: また、「会話の内容を」のところで、ちょっと「ん？」となります。「誰の」会話の内容かがわからないからです。「問題が起こる原因となった、誰かとの会話の内容」？それとも、「あなたがこれから私と話したい会話の内容」？--もし後者なら、「明日からは、何かあったらまずメールで用件を言ってから話しかけてください。」とか「明日からは、何かあったら話しかける前にまずメールで用件を教えてください。」とか、そういうことを言いたいのかな、と思うんですが・・・。（口頭で話しかける前にいちいち用件をメールで言え、なんてのも変な話ですが。。。）

Comment: SE should work more on supporting multiple authorship answers ; )

Comment: @Sqrtbottle it does.  That's what "community wiki" is for.

Answer (score 1):

> 明日から、問題が有れば、私に話す前に、まずメールで会話の内容を送信します。お願いします。

I won't be able to understand what you mean. Do you mean something like 明日から、問題があれば直接私に話しかける前に、まずメールで内容を教えてください ?